# When a text box is on focus, how can I make a listen to a down arrow press

Tags: javascript, dom-events

1. when a text box is on focus, how can I make a listen to a down and up arrow press?
2. how can I get the focus on an element using codes?

### Update

I want this for an auto-complete search. It's working; all I want now when the down arrow key is pressed while typing, the focus moves to the drop-down list.

Comment: What do you want on up/down keys? Select next/previous text-fields?

Comment: no I'm making an auto-complete search. it's working all I want now when the down arrow key is pressed the focus moves to the drop-down list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `onkeydown` event:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="myFunc(this, event)" />
```

and inside the function check the key code to identify which key was pressed using the code:

```
function myFunc(sender, e) {
    var key = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (key === 38) {
        // up arrow was pressed
    }
}
```

and here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76MSg/1/).

As far as setting the focus to a given element is concerned you could use the [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.focus) function:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_element').focus();
```

Comment: what's the `which/keycode` for down arrow? does this work for all browsers?. thank you ^^

Comment: @SamiAl-Subhi, the code for down arrow is 40. The which/keyCode make this code cross browser as depending on the browser it is either one or the other property which will contain the key code.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a library for this kind of stuff; John Resig's [jQuery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) does the job most of the time. You can bind and unbind a hotkeys handler using the focus and blur events:

```
handlerFn = function() { ... };
$('input.my-text-box').focus($(document).bind('keyup', 'down', handlerFn);
$('input.my-text-box').blur($(document).unbind('keyup', handlerFn));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an excelent `jQuery` [plugin](http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/jq-plugins/259-jquery-keyz-plugin.html) named `keyz` to detect which key was pressed alng with `ctrl`, `alt`, `shift` combinations also. I have setup a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/JUbXN/). You can move focus from one textbox to another using arrow keys (up/down).